# why I got 'A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'localPath' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<int>>'?

Tags: flutter, list, file, dart

Hello everyone I'm trying to create a list contains values in .txt file and then chunk it into sublists.
But when I try to return the chunk list I got this error:

> A value of type 'List' can't be returned from the method 'localPath' because it has a return type of 'Future<List>

this is my code :

```
  Future<List<int>> localPath() async {
    final textasset = "assets/112936-bluetooth.txt";
    final text = await rootBundle.loadString(textasset);
    final bytes =
        text.split(',').map((s) => s.trim()).map((s) => int.parse(s)).toList();
    print(bytes);
    final chunks=[];
    int chunkSize = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += chunkSize) {
      chunks.add(bytes.sublist(
          i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
      print(chunks);
    }
    return chunks;
  }
```

this is a screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: No need to use Future when you are using async await, List<int> this should be your return type

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing at below line

```
chunks.add(bytes.sublist(i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
```

is, you are adding a List<int>(which is the sublist of bytes) inside a List named chunks.

Which makes chunks dataType List<List<int>>

and your return type for the function localPath() is Future<List<int>> which is incorrect.
It should be Future<List<List<int>>>.

Solution 1.

```
Future<List<List<int>>> localPath() async {
  const textasset = "assets/112936-bluetooth.txt";
  final text = await rootBundle.loadString(textasset);
  final bytes = text.split(',').map((s) => s.trim()).map((s) => int.parse(s)).toList();
  print(bytes);
  final List<List<int>> chunks = [];
  int chunkSize = 20;
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.add(bytes.sublist(i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
    print(chunks);
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

Solution 2.

If required you can try

```
chunks.addAll(bytes.sublist(i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
```

it will merge all the sublists into chunks and you wont need to change above things.

```
Future<List<int>> localPath() async {
  const textasset = "assets/112936-bluetooth.txt";
  final text = await rootBundle.loadString(textasset);
  final bytes = text.split(',').map((s) => s.trim()).map((s) => int.parse(s)).toList();
  print(bytes);
  final List<int> chunks = [];
  int chunkSize = 20;
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.addAll(bytes.sublist(i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
    print(chunks);
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

Comment: the first solution works very well thank you very much but unfortunately I want that the function returns List<int> not <List<List<int>>>

Comment: then you can use the second solution. if it works..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the dataType on  `chunks` like

```dart
  final List<int> chunks = [];
```

Use `chunks.addAll` instead of `.add` to return `List<int>`.

```dart
Future<List<int>> localPath() async {
  final textasset = "assets/112936-bluetooth.txt";
  final text = await rootBundle.loadString(textasset);
  final bytes =
      text.split(',').map((s) => s.trim()).map((s) => int.parse(s)).toList();
  print(bytes);
  final List<int> chunks = [];
  int chunkSize = 20;
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.addAll(bytes.sublist(
        i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));
    print(chunks);
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

Comment: I got this error  The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int' in this line: `chunks.add(bytes.sublist(
i, i + chunkSize > bytes.length ? bytes.length : i + chunkSize));`

Comment: use `chunks.addAll`

Comment: the .addAll didn't give me the same result as .all. it didn't chunks the list into sublists

Comment: you like to return a  list<subList> ?